# How do I vertically center things?

Tags: html, css, layout

[This](http://www.mrizen.com/wow) is a page I'm trying to develop. I want the text in the tab and the movie in the bubble to be centered. None of the things I've found work properly. Everything on this page is `position: absolute` and defined in percentages, except actual content inside bubbles.

index.css

```
#movie {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    ...
}
#movie-bubble {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
```

root.css

```
.tab {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: to the people saying `display: table-cell`, &c: this does not work.

Comment: vertical-align only affects inline and inline-block elements

Comment: What I found helpful: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ and http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the div it's in to `display: table;`

and the text you're trying to center to:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://f.cl.ly/items/203E123z122t43033D3I/Screen%20shot%202012-12-01%20at%203.03.32%20PM.png
CLearly, it works :P

Answer (score 0):

To centre content inside a `div`, do the following:

To the outside `div`:

```
display: table;
```

To the inside `div`:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
 .area { 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 300px; 
background: url(../images/abe-bg.png) no-repeat; 
position: relative;
}

 .bubble { 
 position: absolute; 
 left: 93px; 
 top: 21px; 
  width: 135px; 
height: 84px; 
 display: table; 
}

.bubble p {
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle; 
 text-align: center; 
}
```

Check this out:- http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/